# SQL Case/IF Statement within Join?

Tags: sql-server

I have the  following statement and while the output works in a way, I'm trying to lay out the joins where I get the customer, group, or master group data in a way that I'm not going to get a bunch of blank columns for the sales rep and discount codes that will tie to the item based on the join below. Ultimately this is going in PowerBI and I'm trying to get a a Master Group, Group, or Cust to all populate if in place (customers can fall within a group or master group, and groups can fall within a master group) and then only get one sales rep or discount code column.

```
SELECT top 5             
P.Item#                         AS Item_No
, I.Description                 AS Item_Desc
, I."Class Description"         AS Class_Desc
, I."Vendor Name"               AS Vendor_Name
, I."Landed Cost"               AS Landed_Cost
, I."Current Price 1"           AS Base_Price
, P."Price Exception"           AS Locked_Price
, P."From DTTM"                 AS Locked_From_DTTM
, P."To DTTM"                   AS Locked_To_DTTM
, P.Customer#                   AS Customer_No
, C1."Ship Name"                AS Customer_Name
, C2."Group Name"               AS Customer_Group
, C3."Master Group Name"        AS Customer_Master_Group
, C1."Sales Rep Name"           AS Sales_Rep
, C2."Sales Rep Name"           AS Sales_Rep_Group
, C3."Sales Rep Name"           AS Sales_Rep_Master_Group
, C1."Discount Code"            AS Discount_Code    
FROM "Promotion Pricing" P           
LEFT JOIN ItemStat I
     ON P.Item# = I.Item#
LEFT JOIN CustStats C1
     ON P.Customer# = C1.Cust#
LEFT JOIN CustStats C2
     ON P.Group# = C2."Cust Group#"
LEFT JOIN CustStats C3
     ON P.Group# = C3."Master Group#"
```

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: Please consider formatting your code so it is readable -- we are here helping you spend the five minutes to delete the unneeded garbage characters.   Then provide input data and expected output.  What you have is not clear.

Comment: I have removed the mysql tag, as this is using SQL server exclusive syntax ("TOP x")

Comment: It's a `CASE` **expression**. `Case` statements don't exist on T-SQL. And don't use a `CASE` Expression in an `ON`; use proper Boolean logic.

Comment: ISNULL(column_name,'Default_Bucket_Group') for joins. so where you have isnull(P.Group#,'Default_Group'), isnull(P.Customer#,'Default_Customer') . etc...

Comment: @junketsu `ISNULL` is just as bad an idea

Comment: Sample data and expected output would be nice.

Comment: @Larnu why is ISNULL a bad idea... seems fine to me.

Comment: It ruins SARGability, @Hogan , which could be a (big) performance impact.

Comment: @Larnu I don't know about ISNULL on MS SQL but I've always found that using COALESCE is well optimized for this use case.

Comment: `COALESCE` would have the same effect, @Hogan, as it's just an abbreviated `CASE` expression; and a `CASE` expression is not SARGable either. Boolean logic is always the way to go. So instead of `A.Col1 = ISNULL(B.Col2,B.Col3)` the "correct" syntax would be `A.Col1 = B.Col2 OR (B.Col2 IS NULL AND A.Col1 = B.Col3)`.

Comment: @Larnu -- I don't understand, you just show the transformation from COALESCE to Boolean.   Why wouldn't a compiler be able to do that?

Comment: Because it doesn't @Hogan . It sees expressions and compares them. It doesnt replace `ISNULL` with some `OR` clauses; thats for you the developer to do.

Comment: @Larnu --- let me rephrase that --- I know DB2 does that optimization, I'd expect other enterprise tier products to do the same.

Comment: No, SQL Server does not so this. SQL Server is not DB2.